Why is an inode allocated when creating a socket in kernel?
in the kernel source code allocates an inode when creating a socket, but it's not used afterwards. I'm not sure why it's allocated without being used. It's not simply because sockets are treated as files, as sockets have a file structure as a member. Is there a reason for this allocation, or can we identify where the inode is used in the kernel's socket API?
And I'm analyzing the socket API in kernel code. Are there any good resources or courses available?

struct socket sock_alloc(void)
{ 

    struct inode *inode;   

    struct socket *sock;  

 
    inode = new_inode_pseudo(sock_mnt->mnt_sb); 

    sock = SOCKET_I(inode); 

 ...

    return sock; 

} 


Perhaps it's needed for the socket to be a "file" descriptor?

And which version of the Linux kernel are you looking at?

Probably for SockFS.

(Note: SockFS is mounted inside the kernel, not in userspace. But you should see some entries with this /bin/sh command: { ls -ld /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null; } | grep ' -> socket:'.)

An answer could be there (to be slightly more precise than @IanAbbott): https://www.linux.org/threads/pipefs-sockfs-debugfs-and-securityfs.9638/
